# Applying postprocessing effect on certain 3D objects only

Tags: glsl, webgl, three.js

First i am a beginner in glsl and Three.js :).

Here are my vertex and fragment shader (very simple) of shader1:

```
 void main() {

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position,1.0);             
}       

void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

In my init() function there is:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffaaff});
cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

var effect1 = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ShaderExtras[ "shader1" ]);
effect1.renderToScreen=true;
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer);
composer.addPass(renderScene);
composer.addPass(effect1);
```

In my function render() :

```
Renderer.clear() ;
composer.render();
```

But at the end all my screen is red not only my cube. What's wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to say hello :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Three.js, but the way you're installing your shader looks like it's being used as a full-screen post-processing effect, not applied to your geometry — and since you unconditionally make output pixels red, the entire screen is red. You need to use some other operation to tell Three.js that you want your shader to be used for rendering your cube (or all geometry in the scene).

Answer (score 0):

To apply postprocessing shaders to certain screen regions, or objects, you need to use stencils (OpenGL term).

It's a little complex topic, so I suggest you either read about them in generic OpenGL tutorial or study existing Three.js examples doing stencils.

I think this example did something related:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_postprocessing.html

Comment: That example doesn't use stencils. It doesn't even specify a renderTarget.